# Why does the page/post ID keep growing when i refresh the post-new.php file?

Tags: id

I created a custom post type and for debugging reasons i display the Post ID on the Add New ... page. If i refresh the page without saving or even creating a new post,(so i just press f5 on the post-new.php) the post ID is growing one by one.

Why is this happening and is this the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, as I understand it.

When you load the page `post-new.php`, you run this function:

```
$post = get_default_post_to_edit( $post_type, true );
```

where the second argument stands for `$create_in_db`. If true then this part is executed:

```
if ( $create_in_db ) {
            $post_id = wp_insert_post(...);
}
```

inside `get_default_post_to_edit()`.

Comment: Thanks, i don't worry about this then, but its still a little strange i think...:)